# Deploy rabbitmq to Azure

Tags: azure, docker, rabbitmq, containers, azure-web-app-service

I want to deploy rabbitmq:3-management-alpine docker image to Azure. At first place I wanted to use a docker image inside Azure App service Environment and created a web app for containers but I figured out it seems it is not possible to expose different management ports (SSL port 5671 and 15671) for a web app. By default it only supports 80 and 443. I wanted to use web app, because this makes my life easier to manage SSL configuration.

Anyway, after realized the fact, I thought I can use azure container instances but I dont know how can I manage ssl configuration and environment variables default users admin users..etc with container instances. Can you help me to designate yaml configuration of rabbitmq with SSL? as well as certificate copy..etc?

Thanks,

Comment: Two options really. If you just want a pub/sub system look at Azure Service Bus, it does more or less the same thing but over the improved AMQP 1.0 protocol. If you need RabbitMQ, deploy it on a pair of VMs or on Azure Kubernetes Service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way to deploy rabbitmq to azure was container instances.

Comment: I'm trying to do this but I'm not finding it easy at all.  What are the steps to deploy rabbitmq to ACI?

Comment: But how to deploy to App Service? Container Instances are not configurable at "runtime" and I can't see logs from Azure Portal